# Testing a post route with pytest failing with 400 status code

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I am trying to run a simple post test against my API where I register a user. The route works fine. However my test keeps failing with the following error:

```
E       assert 400 == 201
E         -400
E         +201

src/tests/test_UserView.py:34: AssertionError
```

The relevant code from my `test_UserView.py` is posted below.

```
import pytest, json

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("client")
class TestUserView:

    def test_user_creation(self, client):
        """
        Test user creation with valid credentials
        """

        url = '/v1/users/'

        mimetype = 'application/json'

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': mimetype,
            'Accept': mimetype
        }

        data = {
            'username': 'webby',
            'email': 'webby@example.com',
            'password': 'w3bby12345',
            'first_name': 'Mike',
            'dob': '1973-03-03',
            'last_name': 'Webb',
            'city': 'Temple Hills',
            'state_provence': 'Maryland',
            'country': 'USA'
        }
        response = client.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        assert response.content_type == mimetype
        assert response.status_code == 201
```

Comment: Is the `url` variable passed to the post request complete? Seems to be an incomplete path.

Comment: It is correct because I have a similar test that is working that uses the same type of url path.

Comment: may be check it with `response.url`